# Trying to extract information in a casual manner - Which word or phrase can be best used to describe it?

Tags: phrases, expressions, verbs

Someone (person  A) is trying to extract information in a conversation in a casual manner, probably with malintent, without the other person (person B) noticing that they (B) are actually divulging information. How can we better describe the action? Words like 'inquire' and 'probe' doesn't satisfy unknowingly part

Comment: Doing something "unknowingly" means that the person performing the action does not know that they are doing it. Assuming that is not the case and your subject is trying not to let other people know what they are doing, they would be extracting information "surreptitiously,"  "secretively," "covertly," or "clandestinely."

Comment: ...maybe snoop? But your Q is unclear. How does someone have bad intentions without knowing what they are doing?

Comment: "Unknowing" and "with malintent" are oxymoronic. Either they are doing it deliberately and malicously (malintent) or they are doing it subconciously and without meaning to (unknowingly). Which are you trying to describe?

Comment: She wanted to know his true intentions.  She had a plan for *getting them out of* him.

Comment: Apologies for making question unclear. She is trying to extract information in a casual conversation, without him not knowing that she is extracting information

Comment: I added person A and B in the edit, since I think the identity of 'they' was confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'[Fishing](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/fishing) for information' might be what you're looking for

> 17.to seek to obtain something indirectly or by artifice: to fish for compliments; to fish for information.